# ng test is giving error with firefox browser

Tags: angular, karma-runner

Getting below error while running ng test, ( Firefox browser is added with Karama.conf.js )
Cannot load browser "Firefox": it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following dependencies resolves the issue:

```
plugins: [
      require('core-js/es6/promise'),
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-ie-launcher'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-firefox-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      'karma-spec-reporter'
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your karma config file to see the firefox plugin listed,

plugins : [
    'karma-junit-reporter',
    'karma-chrome-launcher',
    'karma-firefox-launcher'
    ],

Comment: Added and installed - npm install karma-junit-reporter --save-dev. Now I'm getting below error: ERROR [karma-server]: Server start failed on port 9876: Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)

Comment: try to add 'karma-jasmine' also to the plugins array or try to install karma jasmine globally.

npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev

Comment: Added 'karma-jasmine' in plugins array, Installed karma-jasmine [npm install karma-jasime --save-dev] also installed [npm install karma-firefox-launcher --save-dev]. Now getting this error: ERROR [karma-server]: Server start failed on port 9876: Error: No provider for "framework:@angular-devkit/build-angular"! (Resolving: framework:@angular-devkit/build-angular)

Comment: Where did you get this karma.conf file? is it not angular cli standard ? It is always recommended to create the project structure using angular cli. Or otherwise you can use a boilerplate projects for karma such as this,
https://github.com/jesperorb/karma-boilerplate

Comment: Its in my project from a long time and working fine with Chrome browser. The issue is with Firefox browser only. I installed this [npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular] but getting the same error for Firefox. I am currently using Angular 7 framework.

Comment: Added below dependencies with plugins resloved the issue:                  plugins: [    
     require('core-js/es6/promise'),
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-ie-launcher'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-firefox-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      'karma-spec-reporter' ]